# Populate datagridview from database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, cassandra

I am trying to fill datagridview from database (cassandra), but for some reason it shows only one row instead of two, can you tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
    public void show_db()
    {

        var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
        var session = cluster.Connect("hotel");

        RowSet rs = session.Execute("SELECT * FROM hotel.staff");


        foreach (var res in rs)
        {
            for (int i = 0; 2 < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    staff_info.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = res.GetValue<string>("staff_id");
                    staff_info.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = res.GetValue<string>("username");
                    staff_info.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = res.GetValue<string>("password");
                    staff_info.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = res.GetValue<string>("name");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[It's from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56iDw.png)

[This is from the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug8H0.png)

Comment: I want to apologize for a foolish question...

Comment: That can't be your actual code, you have an infinite loop.